# How can i implement row or table locking using visual studio 2015 ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I want to add in multi-user access feature whereby concurrency wont occur in my web application, is there any method that is easy and simple to implement ?

Comment: Those would be features of the *underlying* database engine - not of Visual Studio.

Comment: @marc_s underlying database engine such as mySQL? May i know how to do it ?

Comment: Yes, exactly - and it depends on which RDBMS you're using on how to do it. For SQL Server, I would **strongly** recommend **NOT** to do it at all! Handling the few cases of concurrency is a lot simpler than having locks that you need to manage and possibly break (if someone walks away from their PC, leaving a lock in place...)

Comment: This can be done through database isolation level (affects the whole database), through adding locking statements to your SQL and using transactions to affect those locks lifetime, or by using custom logic to determine whether or not to update some data based on some related value.  However, each approach gives as many drawbacks as it does benefits (if there was something that just fixed concurrency without a downside, that would be built in to your database's logic OOTB and you wouldn't need to ask this question).  What is the issue you're currently facing?

Comment: @marc_s  i am doing it for a few tables as these few tables will require multi-user access. for example, user A updates while user B waits till user a finish before update.   is there sql statements to turn on the locking feature?

Comment: @JohnLBevan I am not able to find a solution to my web application, where i want to have multi -user access for some of the tables that is use and updated frequently. The main problem is to not let two user update at the same time, as the information updated will not be correct. However, i want it to be done in visual studio database. According to marc_s, i have to do it through underlying database engine.

Comment: @user7093382; @marc_s is correct in pointing out that Visual Studio is an editor, so isn't relevant to the question (it's like saying "What seasoning should I add to my soup using a saucepan"; the saucepan doesn't affect the seasoning; though is one of a variety of tools you can use to heat your soup.

Comment: @user7093382 in terms of locking; you're looking at a pessimistic locking strategy; i.e. open a transaction, put a lock on the record(s) being updated as you read them, run your update statements against them, then commit your transaction which clears the locks.  The issue with this approach is that you'll get blocking; i.e. whilst your record's locked others won't be able to update it, so their requests will be queued.  You may want to read more about this here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114262/ways-of-doing-locking-in-NET-Pessimistic-and-opt#What%20is%20pessimistic%20locking

Comment: Sadly no time to knock up a better solution for you atm; will revisit when I do in case you've not had an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Although you can specify locking hints in code, generally, locking is transparent in most rdms and use the locking characteristics of the underlying engine.

Are you asking for exclusive access to a resource? If so then one option would be to use the `sp_getapplock` system stored procedure. You can place your critical section logic in a transaction and use the built in locking of sql server to ensure synchronized access.

```
CREATE PROC MyCriticalWork(@MyParam INT)      
AS
    DECLARE @LockRequestResult INT
    SET @LockRequestResult=0

    DECLARE @MyTimeoutMiliseconds INT
    SET @MyTimeoutMiliseconds=5000--Wait only five seconds max then timeouit

    BEGIN TRAN

    EXEC @LockRequestResult=SP_GETAPPLOCK 'MyCriticalWork','Exclusive','Transaction',@MyTimeoutMiliseconds
    IF(@LockRequestResult>=0)BEGIN

        /*
        DO YOUR CRITICAL READS AND WRITES HERE
        */

        --Release the lock
        COMMIT TRAN
    END ELSE
        ROLLBACK TRAN
```